# Beginner: Finding an image path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Hello and sorry for such a basic question, but I have exhausted all search options.

My question is how do I find an image path? I am starting to learn Ruby on Rails and a gem I am trying to integrate requires me to specify an image path:

```
colors = Miro::DominantColors.new('/path/to/local/image.jpg')
```

How do I find the path to a local image saved to my desktop?

I am trying to use the Miro RoR gem (https://github.com/jonbuda/miro).

Thank yo,
Brian

Comment: right click on img and choose properties, is this what you need?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to [upload the image](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip)

---

**Images**

The problem you've got is Rails is server-side

You're trying to load an image from your client-side system (your desktop)

This means that in order to get Rails to process the image in any way, you will have to first upload the image into the system, then process it. The recommended way to do this is to use the [Paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) (for image uploads), then you can use your [Miro gem](https://github.com/jonbuda/miro) to process the image

Here's what I'd do:

---

**Upload**

You'll first have to upload the image

There are numerous ways to do this, but the process is the same:

1. Create `image` model & db (to store the image)
2. Create `upload` form
3. Process `upload` through `controller`

Model

```
#app/models/image.rb
Class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :image
end
```

Controller

```
#app/controllers/images_controller.rb
def new
    @image = Image.new
end

def create
    @image = Image.new(image_params)
    @image.save
end

private
def image_params
    params.require(:image).permit(:image)
end
```

View

```
#app/views/images/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @image do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Process**

After saving the image, you can then call one of [Paperclip's processing methods](http://matthewhutchinson.net/2010/10/25/editing-file-uploads-with-a-paperclip-processor) to manage the uploaded image's processing. Here are some ideas on how you may do this:

- [Paperclip Processing Tutorial](http://matthewhutchinson.net/2010/10/25/editing-file-uploads-with-a-paperclip-processor)
- [Paperclip Image Processing using DelayedJob](http://madeofcode.com/posts/42-paperclip-s3-delayed-job-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice and links to paperclip tutorials, Rich. I'll definitely be using those resources in the near future.

The solution was too simple, and I feel guilty for asking the question haha. All I had to do was use terminal to navigate to the image then just $pwd to get the path.